# table td row Overlap on the table header

Tags: html, css

Im creating table at first and then i get data with `ajax` and create `td` and put a `div` in it,
but `div` which is in the `td` comes over `table` header throw scrolling.

Table Header Style:

```
table th {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, blue, yellow);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'BRoya';
    font-weight: bold;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

As you see `div` inside of `tr` comes over `table` header

[image]

Comment: Obviously cause it's sticky and top: 0. I think you haven't tested much to fix it on yourself.

Comment: @Archer i cant change because i want to my table headers be fixed in scroll

Comment: Look like you need z-index 1 in th !!!

Answer (score 0):

can you please share the table code structure so that i can check the actual problem please update the complete code

for you understanding i am sharing the proper structure of html table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th><div>Company</div></th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>Dummy</div></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

also it is happen due to this remove this css it will be fine thanks

```
table th {
top:0;
}
```